# What is the Tomcat equivalent of IIS's web.config file?

Tags: iis, configuration, tomcat7

I'd like to have environment-specific application settings in my Java/Tomcat web app.  When I developed in .NET on IIS I had the good old web.config file to help me out with this.  Does Tomcat have something equivalent to IIS's web.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**web.config** is basically the application's config file. So in **Tomcat/Java EE** it's the **web.xml** which is part of the webapp.